# Android - RuntimeException trying to Turn on flash while capture video

Tags: android, android-camera

I build an app which first open flash and and start processing video, this works good.
I have a button which just turn off/on flash light. In my device and other devices I it works good but on some devices it returns :

java.lang.RuntimeException: setParameters failed when calling mCamera.setParameters(p);

So, the button onClick code is:

```
     Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
     parameters.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH); // flash on
     mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
```

Any ideas what can cause the problem ? thank in advance

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the device(s) in question don't support FLASH_MODE_TORCH. Try setting it to FLASH_MODE_ON instead and see if you get the same error.

Comment: As I said, the flash starts and works good, but when I try to set it off/on it still happened so the devices support this parameter. thanks anyway